# django, nginx, gunicorn 404 on any other page than the root

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

My issue is that whenever I try to view a webpage that isn't the root webpage aka /user/ nginx returns a 404 error and the error log states 
"/usr/share/nginx/html/user/login/index.html" is not found.

current nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip_address;

    location = /static {
         root /opt/scrumban/kanbanboard/;
         autoindex off;
     }

    location = / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/opt/scrumban/kanbanboard/kanban.sock;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove those `=` signs; they mean that only the paths  "/" and "/static" are matched. Without the symbol they match as prefixes, which is what you want.